# Does Crawmerax drop better items when playing as a team?

Tags: borderlands

I noticed Crawmerax is considerably harder to beat as a team (either that or he's quite easy for me to solo as a Siren), does he actually drop better guns when beaten as a team or does he just drop more of them?

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think he drops more stuff in a team, so there's more chance of a good item per kill

Comment: @yx. I'm almost 100% sure that he drops more items when you're in a party, I'm just wondering if he drops better items on average. It's actually a lot faster for me to kill him solo, so more items doesn't necessarily help.

Comment: Doesn't the whole game scale up in terms of difficulty and loot when playing as a team?

Comment: @Alex difficulty scales up but the enemies levels doesn't visibly increase. I'm not sure in the loot increases in quality due to that invisible difficulty increase, since they're usually based on visible level.

Comment: I think the rate of rares he drops is the same unless one of your team members have the increased chance to find rare items team mod.

Answer (score 2):

he does. the more people you have in your game, the more loot and the better loot everything will drop. its halfway why i love to play the game with friends :D

Answer (score 1):

Having a mod with +1 or +2 find rare items generally results in better loot than playing with another person without a plus to find rare, at least in my experience.

Mind you, having a team where everyone has a plus for find rare items (I've got ones for the hunter and the siren, not sure if ones for the others drop) would probably result in the best chance. :)